# Drop temp table if it exists on SQL Azure

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, temp-tables

Is there better way to drop temp table on **Azure SQL**?

```
BEGIN TRY
    DROP TABLE #customMap
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Maybe there is no need to drop temp tables on Azure SQL since tables are dropped when session is ended.

This

```
if (OBJECT_ID('#candidates')) is not null
begin
    drop table #candidates;
end;
```

or this

```
if (OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#candidates')) is not null
begin
    drop table #candidates;
end;
```

does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Azure SQL Database you can use DROP IF EXISTS (DIE) syntax:

```
create table #temp (id int)

drop table if exists #temp
```

Comment: I know this question is about SQL Azure but just as an FYI this returns _Incorrect syntax near 'IF'._ on SQL Azure Datawarehouse

Answer (score 2):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempDB..#myTempName','U') IS NOT NULL
   drop table #myTempName
```

temporary tables are created in `tempDB`, not whatever DB you're currently using as the default db.

Comment: I get `Msg 3701, Level 11, State 5, Line 2
Cannot drop the table 'yarpas', because it does not exist or you do not have permission.`

Comment: @Fosna Everytime this has ever happened to me, it has been because the table name was misspelled in one of the two times it appears in this command.